# Ansible Docker: Execute shell file with container

Tags: docker, ansible, weblogic

I have the following Docker Command:

```
docker run -d  --name ADMIN_SERVER_TEST1 --network=soa_net --ip=172.16.1.11 -p 7001:7001 -v /Oracle_Volumes/ENVIRONMENTS/TEST1/SOA-Volume/cheetah_domain:/u01/oracle/user_projects   --env-file $ENV_HOME/adminserver-test1.env.list --env-file $ENV_HOME/soaserver-test1.env.list -u root redreply/soa-suite:12.2.1.3 ./dockertools/createDomainAndStart.sh && docker logs -f ADMIN_SERVER_TEST1
```

For this command, I have created the following Script with Ansible:

```
  - name: Create SOA container
    docker_container:
      name: "{{ name }}"
      image: "{{ image }}"
      detach: yes
      privileged: yes
      user: root
      volumes:
          - "{{ src_vol }}:{{ dest_vol }}"
      ports:
          - 7001:7001
      networks: 
        - name: soa_net
          ipv4_address: "{{ ip }}"
          env_file: 
            - "{{ env_file_1}}"
            - "{{ env_file_2}}"
```

But I have no clue how to add this part to Ansible script:

```
./dockertools/createDomainAndStart.sh && docker logs -f ADMIN_SERVER_TEST1
```

Comment: You can certainly add a `shell` task to run the `createDomainAndStart.sh` script, but following the Docker logs is not a good idea - Ansible is not a monitoring tool. Do you want to check the logs to see if the server started up, or do you want to use this for monitoring the container for a longer time? There might be different answers depending on what you want to do...

Comment: The logs command we can exclude. I just need it to see the output.

Comment: the shell file needs to be executed with docker container as one Command. If i separate them than both will faile

Comment: Got it - sorry for missing that earlier. Please see my answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your script as the `command` that gets executed in the container when it starts, you can specify that with the `command` attribute like this:

```
  - name: Create SOA container
    docker_container:
      name: "{{ name }}"
      image: "{{ image }}"
      detach: yes
      privileged: yes
      user: root
      command: ./dockertools/createDomainAndStart.sh
      volumes:
          - "{{ src_vol }}:{{ dest_vol }}"
      ports:
          - 7001:7001
      networks: 
        - name: soa_net
          ipv4_address: "{{ ip }}"
          env_file: 
            - "{{ env_file_1}}"
            - "{{ env_file_2}}"
```

I basically added the `command` attribute to call your `./dockertools/createDomainAndStart.sh` script when the container is started.

The [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html) has this description for the `command` attribute:

> Command to execute when the container starts. A command may be either a string or a list. Prior to version 2.4, strings were split on commas.